# не получается составить регулярное выражение

Tags: java, android, регулярные-выражения

Пытаюсь парсить HTML документ, и попутно разбираюсь в регулярках - читал статьи, но как только казалось, что всё понял - на деле оказывается не правильно.

Конкретно - есть строка: `<meta property="og:image" content="http://drugoigorod.ru/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/krov_1.jpg" /><link rel="icon"`

Из неё нужно вытащить `2016/06/krov_1.jpg`.

Вот регулярка, которая у меня получилась по гайдам, что находил и синтаксису, как его понял:

```
private static Pattern headerImagePattern = Pattern.compile("<meta property=\"og:image\" content=\"http://drugoigorod.ru/wp-content/uploads/(.*)\\S/><link rel=\"icon\"");
```

В чем моя ошибка, и почему он не находит так, как я предполагаю?В чем упущение\тонкость.

p.s То, что возвращает этот шаблон прислать не могу, это проверяется в тестах, а логи там почему-то не пашут.

p.s.s сайты проверки регулярок вроде regex101 не подойдут, есть разница в синтаксисах, там для javascript и php, то что работает там, не работает в джаве и наоборот.

Comment: Лично мне кажется, что для вашей задачи проще выдрать информацию при помощи обычных методов `String`

Comment: Да, но это делается что-бы разобраться в регулярках.

Comment: Никогда, слышите? Никогда не парсите xml регулярками. Вот, например, сюда посмотрите http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Ну, это уж очень не подходящая задача для того, чтобы разобраться в регулярках, как по мне (Я просто не люблю регулярки)

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что не надо парсить XML или HTML регулярками. Просто не надо. Никогда. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3212712

Comment: Посмотри [тут](//bbs.vbstreets.ru/viewtopic.php?p=6770380#p6770380) как надо парсить мета-теги регулярками. На джаве аналогично, только экранирование не проворонить. И вообще, базовый синтаксис (которого тут вполне достаточно) одинаков во всех языках.

Comment: @metalurgus, вполне подходящая.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, с каких пор это причина для закрытия?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб отличный пост, с классной концовкой=)

Comment: @Qwertiy, ну, чтобы люди не тратили кучу времени на бесполезные задачи... Надо брать к-л либу типа JSOUP и парсить ею HTML. Ещё раз продублирую хороший пост на en-SO по этому вопросу: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3212712

Comment: Мужики, вы конечно, можете и закрыть, но подскажите всё же, почему ожидание не соответствует реальности :D?Если уж отойти от того, HTML это или нет, просто есть строка, пускай и с тегами, и некая регулярка, которая вроде бы должна находить результат, но на деле это не так.

Comment: @Asgard, ну, лично я не виу в вопросе составленного вами выражения, кое не работает.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Pattern.compile("<meta property=\"og:image\" content=\"http://drugoigorod.ru/wp-content/uploads/(.*)\\S/><link rel=\"icon\"");

Вот составленное мной выражение, и оно не работает

Comment: конкретно тут проблема в `\S` - это значит "любой символ кроме пробельных (\s)", а вам как раз нужен пробел.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\d{4}/\d{2}
```

`\d`    - [0-9] Цифровой символ

`{4}` - 4 цифры

далее символ /

`\d`    - [0-9] Цифровой символ

`{2}` - 2 цифры

Comment: `Из неё нужно вытащить 2016/06/krov_1.jpg` - точное совпадение :D

Comment: \d{4}/\d{2}/\S+.jpg